# SICP, Fermat Test Issue

Tags: algorithm, sicp

[Section 1.2.6](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.6) of SICP describes an algorithm for Fermat prime testing as follows (my own words):

To test whether `n` is prime:

1. Choose a random integer `a` between `1` and `n-1` **inclusively**.
2. If `a^n %n = a`, then `n` is probably prime.

The part I'm getting stuck on is the fact that we allow `a = 1` because in this case, regardless of our choice of `n` (prime or not), the test will always pass.

Comment: I'm sorry you find the text confusing. If you think it should be written in a less confusing way, you could contact the author. There's nothing anyone here can do about it, and it seems that you understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right; there's no reason to choose a = 1. That being said, the statistical distance between the uniform distribution on [1, n-1] and the uniform distribution on [2, n-1] is O(1/n), so when n is very large (large enough that you don't just want to do trial division), the practical impact is very small (remember that this is already a probabilistic test, so a good number of other choices of a won't work either).

Comment: While you're right that this wouldn't be considered a serious bug in a real-world implementation of the algorithm, in a textbook for students, I think it can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The text you link to actually says (emphasis mine):

> Fermat's Little Theorem: If n is a prime number and a is any positive integer less than n, then a raised to the nth power is congruent to a modulo n.
>
> (Two numbers are said to be congruent modulo n if they both have the same remainder when divided by n. The remainder of a number a when divided by n is also referred to as the remainder of a modulo n, or simply as a modulo n.)
>
> If n is not prime, then, in general, **most of the numbers a < n will not satisfy the above relation**. This leads to the following algorithm for testing primality: Given a number n, **pick a random number a < n** and compute the remainder of a^n modulo n. If the result is not equal to a, then n is certainly not prime. If it is a, then **chances are good that n is prime**. Now pick another random number a and test it with the same method. If it also satisfies the equation, then we can be even more confident that n is prime. **By trying more and more values of a, we can increase our confidence in the result.** This algorithm is known as the Fermat test.

Up until now it never says to actually pick 1. It does later on though. I think that's a mistake, although not a big one. Even if it's true for a given value, you should test multiple values to be sure.

The [pseudocode on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test) uses `[2, n - 1]` as the range for example. You should probably use this range in practice (although the Fermat test isn't really used in practice, since [Miller-Rabin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) is better).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to bring out with quoting the text which precedes the description of the algorithm implementation. My question is on the fact that we allow 1 to be randomly chosen. Even if in the big, real world, picture, it's only a small mistake, as a student reading a pedagogical book like this one, I find it confusing.

Comment: @IsaacKleinman I'm trying to bring out that, if you pay attention to the explanations, you should be less confused, because the book says you need to try more values to be confident in the result.